# Blocking of an .exe download on firefox wrapped with launch4j

Tags: exe, executable, antivirus, launch4j

I use launch4j to wrap a java executable with an embedded jre, my goal is to put this executable on an apache2 server to make it available to my clients to download and install.

The problem: when I try to download it from firefox my antivirus blocks the download and I have no log message to identify the origin of the blocking.
the download works on google chrome and IE.

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on the official website of firefox, if the download is blocked you must clear the download history ! ref. 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/cant-download-or-save-files

:-)